# less with multiple files; command to output filenames

Tags: less

I want to be able to manually go through many files using `less *.txt` and then proceeding through the files using `:n`. If I determine that a file needs to be processed, then I want to be able to give a command that will, for example, send the current file name to stderr, so that once I am done going through all the files, I have a list of filenames to be processed. Is something like this possible? Is there another tool that is better for this purpose?

Comment: how do you decide?  is it arbitrary or subjective, or is it based on objective fact(s) that can be searched for with grep or an awk or perl script?

Comment: The decision is based on factors that would take developing new technology to determine automatically. And besides, going through it by hand is valuable for me to become better acquainted with the data that I am using for machine-learning.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup your own `less` special command key. Create file `~/.lesskey` and place in it, at the
start, the 2 lines:

```
#command
ok shell echo % >>/tmp/list\n
```

Then give the command

```
lesskey
```

to compile the file. Run your `less` command on your files and when you want to
save the filename type the 2 chars `ok`. You will see echoed:

```
!echo myfilename >>/tmp/list
!done  (press RETURN)
```

which saves the current filename (%) into `/tmp/list`.  Press return to continue.
I chose the command `ok` arbitrarily. You can use any single character or character sequence you like.
You can append the `:n` command to the end of the `shell` line in `~/.lesskey` to also move
on to the next file.

---

If you don't have `lesskey` I ran it on the above file and passed it through `base64` as it contains
some binary. Perhaps you can try using this:

```
echo 'AE0rR2MaAG9rAJtlY2hvICUgPj4vdG1wL2xpc3QKOm4AZQAAdgAAeEVuZA==' | base64 -d >~/.less
```

Comment: This looks fantastic, but there is no `lesskey` on my OS X 10.8.5.

Comment: bad luck. it seems to be mentioned by the [less manpage here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/less.1.html), so I don't know why they forgot it.

Comment: I added the binary output to my answer. It might work.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write a script that will do things with the least keystrokes, but if you have no time to write and thoroughly test a script, depending on what version of less you have, yes it is possible to use less.

Tested with `less` version 444, here is a sample walkthrough.

First, suppose you have four files a.txt b.txt c.txt d.txt

```
$ less *.txt
```

a.txt looks fine, so you view next using `:n`

b.txt looks bad, so to mark it you type:

```
! echo % | tee -a bad.txt
```

Less will respond:

```
b.txt
!done  (press RETURN)
```

You continue `:n`.

c.txt looks ok. You continue with `:n`

d.txt looks bad too, but you don't have to retype every single keystroke again, just `!` and up-arrow, it will auto fill last command, and save `d.txt` to `bad.txt`

Then you `q` to quit less.

Now you can review the saved list:

```
$ cat bad.txt
b.txt
d.txt
```

### Explanation

- The `! shell command` runs of course a shell command, where % is the current file
- using `tee` is optional, just to have an additional indicator after you run the command, of what filename you just saved.
- `-a` appends, otherwise would overwrite and your bad.txt just has a single record
- you could have also just `! echo % >> bad.txt` to append to bad.txt

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do something like this, I'll use a tabbed terminal with `less` in one tab and `vi` in an adjacent tab.

When I get to a file I want to tag, I'll double-click on the filename at the bottom of the `less` screen, switch to the `vi` tab, middle-click paste it and hit `ENTER`, then switch back to the `less` tab.

If there's more than a couple of dozen files (i.e. it's likely to take me more than a few minutes), I'll try to figure out some way of automating the selection process with one or more of the usual tools: `grep`, `awk`, `perl`, etc.

`grep` for simple searches, `awk` or `perl` for more complicated ones.